# Как получить token api vk

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, oauth2, token

Добрый день, я делаю регистрацию через vk в своем мобильном приложении.

Есть такой метод public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) , и как я понимаю

res - это и есть токен, который выдается после авторизации через вк.

Если вывести этот res в лог, то мы увидим com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken@531dd110213k23

Как я понял, запись после @ - это и есть токен. Т.е токеном является "531dd110213k23" вот эта запись.

Собственно вопрос, как  из res (com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken@531dd110213k23) получить  чистый токен(который после собачки), ведь он не фиксированного размера , а может быть и длинным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в callback от vk

```
@Override
                public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                   // это будет твой токен
                     res.accessToken;    
                }
```